# returning nested json values using loop (google spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-sheets, javascript-objects

I have this google spreadsheet script that pulls in json formatted book data. I have no problem displaying book title and author, but he "offerData" object can contain a different amount of elements (prices from sellers) depending on the book. Right now I created a loop and am storing the offerData values like so:

```
   price[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["price"];
   condition[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["condition"];
   seller[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["seller"]["displayName"];
```

and am returning the data like this:

```
 var resultRow = [[title, specstag, price[0], condition[0], seller[0], price[1], condition[1], seller[1], price[2], condition[2], seller[2]]];
```

Obviously this only returns 3 sellers with price, condition, seller info. The issue is that a book doesn't always have 3 sellers, it can be anywhere from 1 to 10 or so.

My question is how can I return all offerData (price/condition/seller) here? :

```
 var resultRow = [[title, specstag, price[0], condition[0], seller[0], price[1], condition[1], seller[1], price[2], condition[2], seller[2]]];
```

--

```
function getBookDetails(isbn) {

// Query the book database by ISBN code.

if (isbn !== "") { 

var url = "https://api.bol.com/catalog/v4/search/?apikey=myapi6&offers=all&format=json&q=" + isbn;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var results = JSON.parse(response);


if (results.totalResultSize) {

// There'll be only 1 book per ISBN
var book = results.products[0];

// get Title and Authors
var title = (results.products[0]["title"]);
var specstag = (results.products[0]["specsTag"]);

var offerdata = results.products[0]["offerData"];

if (typeof offerdata.offers !== 'undefined' && offerdata.offers.length > 0) {
var arrayLength = offerdata.offers.length;
var price = [];
var condition = [];
var seller = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

  price[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["price"];
  condition[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["condition"];
  seller[i] = offerdata.offers[i]["seller"]["displayName"];

  }
 }    
}

var resultRow = [[title, specstag, price[0], condition[0], seller[0], price[1], condition[1], seller[1], price[2], condition[2], seller[2]]];


return resultRow;

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer

```
var resultRow = [];
resultRow[0] = [];
resultRow[0][0]=title;
resultRow[0][1]=specstag;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i=1+3) {
  resultRow[0][3*i+2]=price[i];
  resultRow[0][3*i+3]=condition[i];
  resultRow[0][3*i+4]=seller[i];
}
```

how you should think about it is to see the index of the elements in the array and then find relation between i and the index you want

```
var resultRow = [
  [
    title, //[0][0]
    specstag, //[0][1]
    price[0], //[0][2]
    condition[0], //[0][3]
    seller[0], //[0][4]
    price[1], //[0][5]
    condition[1], //[0][6]
    seller[1], //[0][7]
    price[2], //[0][8]
    condition[2], //[0][9]
    seller[2]//[0][10]
  ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! That's a way to do it :) I did notice one error in the for loop, I changed i=1+3 to i=i+3, and it worked!

Comment: @dean2020 sorry about this mistake , it happen alot with me , can you please accept the answer if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this;

```
var data = {     title: null,
               spcstag: null,
                   pcs: [],
           };

offerData.offers.forEach( p => { var pcsData = {};
                                 !!data.title || data.title = p.title;
                                 !!data.specstag || data.specstag = p.specstag;
                                 pcsData.price = p.price;
                                 pcsData.condition = p.condition;
                                 pcsData.seller = p.seller;
                                 data.pcs.push(pcsData);
                               });
```